# How to retrieve the last usage record from Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a script that is sending a usage record to Stripe like this:

```
\Stripe\SubscriptionItem::createUsageRecord($subscription,
     [   
         'quantity' => $quantity,        
         'timestamp' => time(),     
     ]);
```

But I can't find any way to retrieve this information later when I rerun the script.

This information seems to exists on Stripe. My script runs every hour.

```
Usage from 1/19 to 2/19

To see usage of this product during other periods, view its full usage history.
Date                Units used
Feb 19, 8:00 AM     43
Feb 19, 7:00 AM     42
Feb 19, 6:00 AM     41
Feb 19, 5:00 AM     41
Feb 19, 4:00 AM     40
Feb 19, 3:00 AM     40
Feb 19, 2:00 AM     39
...
```

I found out that I can retrieve [all usage record summaries](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/subscription_item_summary_list?lang=php) but is not what I want.

How can I retrieve the last usage record sent to Stripe?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to retrieve the latest usage record exactly. You should be able to use the [list usage record summaries endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/subscription_item_summary_list?lang=python#usage_record_summary_all-limit) to get the info you need though. The latest item is the first one in the list.

Comment: this endpoint actually returns all usages info accumulated during period and not separately based on report date